Unable to find config file for pgAgent
I have installed PostgreSQL 16 in my local machine. Using Application stack builder, i have installed pgAgent. i have created one service account named as pgagent at the time of setup pgagent. i have create extension pgagent in my database. pgagent service is running under logOn pgagent. i have created one role as pgagent. i gave all the permission to this role. i mean i made it as superuser. I have created one function in my database in schema master_config. this function will execute on table Act and Comp in master_config schema and archive_act in archive schema. i have schedule a job in pgagent using pgAdmin. but the problem is - this job is not executing on given time.
How can i fix this problem.
Note: pgagent service is running properly. Job is enabled, step is enabled, schedule is enabled, i choosed the correct db where i have my tables. i log in server as postgres as superuser. my db user is also postgres. is set the correct code in steps. manually i tested my function is working fine.
please help me to fix the issue.
i tried almost everything, but i haven't find the config file for the pgagent so it might be a problem. so how can i get config file and how can i config the connection. my db is in local amchine.
please give me a solution for Windows 10.
